# PHP - I'm trying to insert information into my table

Tags: php

I dont know why but i cant insert information into my table

I'm not getting mysql errors.

My button code here:

```
<input style="height:30px; width: 120px; font-size: 15px;" type="submit" class="submit" value="Adicionar" name="adicionar"/>
```

And my php code

```
elseif (isset($_GET['adicionar'])) {
      $nacionalidade = $_GET['nacionalidade'];
      $nome = $_GET['nome'];
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $idade = $_GET['idade'];
      $posicao = $_GET['posicao'];
      $pe_preferido = $_GET['pe_preferido'];
      $altura = $_GET['altura'];
      $peso = $_GET['peso'];
      $titulos = $_GET['titulos'];
      $golos = $_GET['golos'];

      $atualizar="INSERT INTO `atletas` (`nome`, `idade`, `posicao`, `pe_preferido`, `altura`, `peso`, `titulos`, `golos`)  VALUES ('{$_GET['nome']}', '{$_GET['idade']}', '{$_GET['posicao']}', '{$_GET['pe_preferido']}', '{$_GET['peso']}', '{$_GET['titulos']}', '{$_GET['golos']}')";

      $sucesso = mysql_query($atualizar);

      echo 'Atleta adicionado com sucesso';

}
```

Comment: You got all those parameters in the URL?Shoudnt they be POST?

Comment: You have 8 columns and 7 values in your insert.

Comment: @Mihai that should be the anwser :-) @user2744048, first of all, do not use the `mysql_` functions, secondly if you have put `or die(mysql_error())` you would have seen the error

Comment: my form is using GET, and i can see all those aparameters in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that the query is right?

Use this -

```
$sucesso = mysql_query($atualizar) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside wrong number of params/values check that data types of columns
are same as data types of values you are inserting